# Content type icons in dropdown menu missing

Tags: plone

I'm uprading to Plone 4 from 3.3.5 and using webcouturier.dropdownmenu 2.3.

With Plone 3.3.5 I was able to see content type icons in dropdown menu, but in Plone 4 they are missing. Actually content type icons are missing from every other itmes than content with mime type.
What could  do to get them back? 
In Theme Settings, I have "Always show icons" setting on.

Comment: The way icons are handled in Plone has changed between Plone 3 and 4; I suspect that `w.dropdownmenu` hasn't been upgraded to follow suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think this is bug, please use the issue tracker of the addon:
https://github.com/collective/webcouturier.dropdownmenu/issues

Comment: I'm going to make a bug report for this. I think w. Dropdownmenu is not working as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

`http://yourplone/@@skins-controlpanel` (you may get it from plone control panel -> themes)

There's an option for it.

Comment: I have "Always show icons" setting on , but I think Martijn is correct that w.dropdownmenu is not fully supporting content type icons. I seem to have icons visible in the menu, only if there is MIME type associated with the item, not with all content types, such as folder or collection.

Comment: I apologize. I've missed it was talking about webcouturier.dropdownmenu.